# Generators of quotient group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$ be a full rank submodule, so that $\mathbb{Z}^n/\Lambda$ is a finite abelian group. Assume that we know a set of generators of $\mathbb{Z}^n/\Lambda$. Can we determine generators of the larger group $\mathbb{Z}^n/(\ell\cdot\Lambda)$ for $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ in terms of generators of $\mathbb{Z}^n/\Lambda$?

**EDIT:** In my case, $\mathbb{Z}^n/\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}/(2)$ and I know two elements $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, s.t. $\langle[x_1],[x_2]\rangle =\mathbb{Z}^n/\Lambda$. Do the cosets $x_i+\ell\Lambda$ generate $\mathbb{Z}^n/(\ell\cdot\Lambda)$?

I have the feeling that $\mathbb{Z}^n/\ell\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}/(\ell)^{n-2} \times \mathbb{Z}/(2\ell)^2$ in this case and so I need the other $n-2$ basis vectors for the generatig system..

Comment: Perhaps I missing something basic here, but...multiply all the generators by $\;\ell\;$ ?

Comment: ..thats embarassing! thanks anyway

Comment: @DonAntonio: Take e.g. $n=1$, $\Lambda=2\Bbb Z$ and $\ell=3$. Then (the coset of) $1$ generates $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ but $3\cdot 1$ does not generate the larger group $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The $n$ standard basis vectors give a generating set for $\mathbb{Z}^n / (\ell \Lambda)$. I think this question needs some more detail in what you're looking for in a set of generators or in a relationship between the two sets of generators for the two quotients.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I specified the question a little more

Comment: That's definitely the right quotient group for your example -- a simple proof of the general fact can be given by putting a basis matrix for $\Lambda$ in Smith normal form.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for that catch. We may impose a condition on being co-prime or something with the original generators.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the canonical map $\Bbb Z^n/(\ell\cdot\Lambda) \to \Bbb Z^n/\Lambda$, and take the full preimage of the given generators.

This will be certainly a generator system, of size multiplied by $\ell$. 
(However, I guess, this is far from optimal, i.e. one could sift this set to obtain a smaller generator set.)